# Rubber is peeling off my Canon 60D grip; what glue should I use to fix it?

Tags: canon-60d, diy, repair

I take good care of my camera but a while back I started noticing that the rubber on the grip and all the other rubber parts that are made of a similar material are starting to peel off. It's starting to feel a bit strange in my hands and I would like to fix it. Is there a specific glue I should use?

Answer (score 2):

I would refer to my answer to this question. The same guy does canon parts as well.

[How to do DIY repair of rubber grips on Nikon cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/how-to-do-diy-repair-of-rubber-grips-on-nikon-cameras/22969#22969)

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at Sugru ([company site](http://sugru.com/about) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugru)), a self-curing plastic silicone.

You can use it to construct a whole new grip or just add some Sugru to improve the grip.

Comment: don't use glue on a camera body like that. There are access panels beneath the grip that would be sealed off to repair/maintenance workers if you do so. Which is a main reason the original grip is glued on using double sided tape rather than superglue.

Comment: It's not really glue, it's more of a clay. I have not used Sugru myself (only seen it), but according to their "About" site: "Once cured, you can remove it with a craft knife and then remove residue with fingernails and tissue paper." Here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/how-to-do-diy-repair-of-rubber-grips-on-nikon-cameras/22969#22969 it is also given as an answer